# UIDatePicker - Output to Label With Timezone, Without Seconds

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker which spits the selected date to a label using the following:

```
-(void)updateLabel:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    self.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]];
}
```

Using df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle, which seems to be the only option which includes timezone I get this output:

```
March 5, 2016, at 2:37:33 PM, MST
```

However, I don't want the seconds there. This is the output I am trying to achieve:

```
Match 5, 2016 at 2:37PM, MST
```

Can someone help a brother out!

Comment: try to format as per ur requirement instead of using long style. Please look at this: https://gist.github.com/romaonthego/5138532

Comment: NSDateFormatter will use whatever format you want; just use `setDateFormat:` and the appropriate format string.